# Sending a notification to user using Node.js

Tags: node.js, notifications

I am looking for a solution to my problem. I have Node.js server serving my web application where user can log in. I want to handle a situation where one user A performs specific action and user B associated with this action gets real life notification. Is there a module that would help me or there is some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is "server push" where the server proactively notifies a user on their site of some activity or event.  In the web browser world these days, there are basically two underlying technology options:

1. [webSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) (or some use [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/), a more feature rich library built on top of webSocket)
2. [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) (SSE).

For webSocket or socket.io, the basic idea is that the web page connects back to the server with a webSocket or socket.io connection.  That connection stays live (unlike a typical http connection that would connect, send a request, receive a response, then close the connection).  So, with that live connection, the server is free to send the client (which is the web page in a user's browser), notifications at any time.  The Javascript in the web page then listens for incoming data on the connection and, based on what data it receives, then uses Javascript to update the currently displayed web page to show something to the user.

For server sent events, you open an event source on the client-side and that also creates a lasting connection to the server, but this connection is one-way only (the server can send events to the client) and it's completely built on HTTP.  This is a newer technology than webSocket, but is more limited in purpose.

In both of these cases, the server has to keep track of which connection belongs to which user so when something interesting happens on the server, it can know which connection to notify of the event.

---

Another solution occasionally used is client-side polling.  In this case, the web page just regularly sends an ajax call to the server asking if there are any new events.  Anything new yet?  Anything new yet?  Anything new yet?  While this is conceptually a bit simpler, it's typically far less efficient unless the polling intervals are spaced far apart, say 10 or 15 minutes which limits the timeliness of any notifications. This is because most polling requests (particularly when done rapidly) return no data and are just wasted cycles on your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notify userB, when both of you are simultaneously online during the action, then use websockets to pass message to a two-way channel to notify userB.

If you want to notify them whenever, regardless of online status, use a message queue.